# python class typing inheritance in

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, types

I really enjoy using the type hints in python, so I'm trying to increase my understanding.  In the scenario provided below `BASE_CLASS = BASE[ENV]` and `BASE[ENV]` should always be of the same type.  So why is it when `Extract` directly inherits the `BASE[ENV]` the type hints arent annotated.

```py
#app/base.py
from typing import Literal
import request


class Base:

    def get_yerp(self):  # ...
        return self._load_yerp()

    def _load_yerp(self) -> Literal['YERP']: ...


class Production(Base):

    def _load_yerp(self):
        with request(...)



class Development(Base):

    def _load_yerp(self):
        with open(...)
```

```py
#app/extract.py
import os
from typing import Dict, Type, Literal
from app import base

ENV: Literal['production', 'development'] = os.getenv('ENV', 'development')

BASE: Dict[str, Type[base.Base]] = {
    'production': base.Production,
    'development': base.Development
}

BASE_CLASS = BASE[ENV]


class Extract1(BASE_CLASS):

    def __init__(self):
        super().get_yerp()#type hint=(method) get_yerp: () -> Literal['YERP']

class Extract2(BASE[ENV]):

    def __init__(self):
        super().get_yerp()#type hint=Any
```

[image: syntax]

Comment: What do you mean "the types hints aren't annotated"? You didn't annotate them. Can you clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: within vs code super().get_yerp()

Comment: see the comments I provided `#type hint=(method) get_yerp: () -> Literal['YERP']`

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't clarify anything. What about those comments? You need to explain *precisely* what you are talking about. Again, taking your question literally, there are no annotations because the source code contains no annotations.

Comment: in vs code in `Extract1` `super().get_yerp()` is highlighted as a method in `green`; `monokai FTW`.  When I hover over the method I get a display that reads `(method) get_yerp: () -> Literal['YERP']`.  In `Extract2` there is no syntax highlighting and hover only provides `get_yerp: Any`

Comment: Listen, you are describing aspects of your text editor/IDE. You mention none of that in your question. You say "given that Extract inherits from BASE[ENV], I think X should happen", where X is "type hints are annotated", but you have not explained **what X means**. Apparently, you mean are askign why your editor/IDE isn't properly inferring something, but we cannot know if you don't provide precise details about your set up and your expectations. We cannot read your mind, we aren't in front of your computer looking at the screen with you

Comment: I edited the post and included a picture

Comment: Is there another way in which type hints are used outside of an IDE?

Comment: May I quote you on that? :) Type hints can be used in many ways. E.g. read with introspection (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object), used with static analysis tools (see https://pypi.org/project/mypy/ and others), and used at runtime to add semantics in any way you can imagine (see e.g. https://typer.tiangolo.com/ and https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).